# Runtime string error C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

i have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Test(){
    string line;
}

int main(){
    cout << "test " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is compilable but when i try to run it, the program stop working. Then use gdb to discover what wrong with my program

```
 (gdb) run
 Starting program: E:\CPP\Program dinamis\a.exe
 [New Thread 4892.0x1d4c]
 test
 Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
 0x6fcc43c3 in libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout () from C:\MinGw\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
```

i dont understand what wrong with it. i use MinGW (G++) as my compiler by typing `g++ -v` :

```
 E:\CPP\Program dinamis>g++ -v
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=g++
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
 Target: mingw32
 Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-
 languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 
 --enable-shared --enable-libgo
 mp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-  
 runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
 Thread model: win32
 gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

but if i write the same code on my visual studio, the program runs well without error. what should i do with my G++

Comment: How are you compiling it?  I've seen that happen when you generate SSE instructions that your processor doesn't support.

Comment: i just use a G++ command like `g++ -o a.exe filename.cpp` @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i found the solution. I am running on windows 8 Operating system and it seems the main problem is on linking process while compiling the source code.

So let say the filename is `mycode.cpp` and i just run the command with additional `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` options like this one:

```
 g++ "mycode.cpp" -o mycode -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using the test function for output, you could use it as follows but not sure why there is any error appearing for you as for me it runs fine under GNU GCC version 4.8.1

Here is a sample of code which uses Test()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Test(){
    string line = "My text Line here!";
    return line;
}

string Test2(){
    return "My text Line2 here!";
}

int main(){
    cout << Test() << endl;
    cout << Test2() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The second test is to illustrate a simpler usage for returning a string, notee as well the function needs to be defined as returning a string as well.

Comment: the program you provided above is still stop working

Comment: what error does it report? and how do you mean stops working?  I ask as It works fine for me in gcc 4.8.1 and ms vs 2010 and 2012

Comment: the program doesnt provide any error detail, it just pop a new window saying "a.exe is stop working". @GMasucci

Comment: it sounds like there may be an issue with something else, as I cant replicate the error you are having.  What version of GCC (I think 4.6.2?) and OS are you using?

Comment: Yes i use GCC version 4.6.2 and i use windows 8 as my OS @gmasucci

Comment: I will spin up a vm tonight with windows 8 and see if I can replicate the error, but so far it seems to work fine under a variety of oses (ubuntu, win xp/vista/7/server 2008).  Like I said will try tonight for you and get back to you

Answer (score -1):

Just a blind shot, try handling main function parameters:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
//...
```

Maybe it's something with the stack...?